# Use nodes to generate a texture of an image cut out with a checkerboard

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, video, node-editor

I'm new to Blender and running against a deadline!

How can I create dynamically with **nodes** a **texture** made up by a **video** with pixels **cut out using a checkerboard pattern**. When I say cut out I mean leaving pixels with transparency there and other pixels with RGB colors from the video.

Just RGB colors have to became checkerboard-cut, **no the transparent background**. The **video is RGBA**.

I cannot use too much subsurf and particles because my GPU is dead now :( , and the only combination of video texture over plane + subsurf + explode + particles that suits my needs depends on this node-generated texture that improves critically the performance.

This is my goal:

[image: video + plane + subsurf + explode + checkerboarded cut out]

Comment: Not really sure what you want.. Something like this? http://www.pasteall.org/pic/79024

Comment: Yup that it is. How can I make it entirely using nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Blender internal

One way is by using a node texture on top of the video texture to influence the alpha:

[image]

Note that the color input on the checker node has an alpha of 0 and the material has *Mask alpha* enabled.

[**Example .blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32373)

## Cycles

In cycles this can be done with a material setup like this:

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Thnx! Is there a way to preview in texture mode this effect? I'm using v2.70 with GSLS, and previewing even shadows with RGBA textures but this effect is not shown. Only when rendering.

Comment: I don't think any of the procedural textures are supported outside of rendered view. You can bake it to an image texture, but it sounds like this is what you were trying to avoid..

Comment: What if I use an external RGBA bitmap for the checkerboard? Still being procedural?

Comment: @Fallouturama Using an external image texture (even tiled) should work in openGL.

Comment: All worked perfect for me. Day saved now :D Thnx!